# How to give answer to an interaction question prehand (i.e.) at the time of exection of a command?

Tags: scripting

While using GROMACS (a software package) for molecular dynamics, the user gets a series of interactive questions. While I understand that in order to avoid a few of these interactive questions, we can pass the value as parameters to the function, for the remaining function I was not able to find any appropriate parameter (so as to pass value prehand). So was puzzled to think, if we can make bash to answer on our behalf using a code. Let me give an example

When we run the code

```
gmx genion -s ions.tpr -o solv_ions.gro -p topol.top -pname NA -nname CL -neutral
```

We get a series of option

```
Select a continuous group of solvent molecules

Group     0 (         System) has 14020 elements
Group     1 (        Protein) has  1095 elements
Group     2 (      Protein-H) has   548 elements
Group     3 (        C-alpha) has    71 elements
Group     4 (       Backbone) has   213 elements
Group     5 (      MainChain) has   283 elements
Group     6 (   MainChain+Cb) has   346 elements
Group     7 (    MainChain+H) has   354 elements
Group     8 (      SideChain) has   741 elements
Group     9 (    SideChain-H) has   265 elements
Group    10 (    Prot-Masses) has  1095 elements
Group    11 (    non-Protein) has 12925 elements
Group    12 (          Other) has    49 elements
Group    13 (            LIG) has    49 elements
Group    14 (          Water) has 12876 elements
Group    15 (            SOL) has 12876 elements
Group    16 (      non-Water) has  1144 elements

Select a group:
```

We will have to manually enter the value 15. Can we automate this entry of 15?
There are two parts to the question. First, we understand what interactive asking has "SOL" and then making the appropriate number entered (Which is 15).
But almost all the time, its value "15" to be passed. So generic solution, just to pass the value also would also be good.

Comment: Have you tried `echo 15 | gmx genion...`? If not please do. If you have and it doesn't work please [edit] your question to tell us that you tried it and why it isn't a suitable solution

Comment: If the echo doesn't work, you'll probably have to use [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/) or a language with an `expect`-like library (e.g. perl's [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) or python's [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect)).   `expect` is a scripting language which can wait for certain patterns on stdin and send particular responses to them.  The perl & python library modules do the same - IMO you're much better off using one of these because learning them is useful for lots of tasks while expect itself has only a single purpose which you'll rarely need.

Comment: python in particular is very popular in scientific computation circles, with its numpy and scipy modules.  perl is very popular in bioinformatics, with the bioperl libs.